# Suggested tag edit got rejected, but is the bottom line of the question

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942039/replace-value-in-array-with-condition/37942229#37942229) and I thought that for future reference it would be good to add the `enumerate` tag as it is the bottom line of the question but the OP probably did not realize it when he asked.

The edit got rejected ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12761097)) and I presume it is because the relation with the tag is not immediate to someone who just reads the question.

What is the appropriate behaviour in a case like this? Shall I just move on or shall I try again with a more descriptive edit comment to explain the relevance of the tag?

Comment: You should be linking to the relevant suggested edit.   http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12761097

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the rejection reason for all three users who rejected the edit states, your edit isn't meaningfully improving the question.  The question isn't more useful with that tag than without it; it's not an essential tag for that question; it is not improving the visibility of that question, which is the expressed purpose of tags.  The tags already on the question are already entirely appropriate to allow the question to be found.

> What is the appropriate behavior in a case like this?

Do nothing; the rejection was correct.

Comment: Thanks I will reconsider the use I make of tag edits then.